# linux equivalent of windows subst command

Tags: linux, windows

In Windows I can map any path to a drive letter using the subst command.  The cool thing about that is, whatever directory I choose becomes the root directory of all subdirectories.  That makes is super easy to navigate, especially in scripts, because I can instantly return to my root.  In this example Z:\ is the same as c:\mydirectory\myfiles:

```
C:\> subst Z: C:\mydirectory\myfiles
```

So if I'm many subdirectories deep, I can get right back to the root:

```
Z:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5> cd \
Z:\>
```

In linux I can use the ln command but it doesn't give me that same capability.  I know I can't map to a drive letter in linux.  I can do `ln -s` but to navigate up I have to go `cd ../../../` or something like that.  It's hard to keep track of all the `../` needed.  .  If I go `cd /` in linux I get the root of the server, not even my own area on it.  Even within the tree that's ln'd, I can't easily jump to the root like I can with subst.

Am I missing something?

thanks

RACER

Answer (score 1):

You can try the alias command...

```
alias cdz='cd /mydirectory/myfiles'
```

Then you just type cdz and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I use my .bashrc file and and short cuts that way.

```
export WH="/mnt/c/Users/Shanzem/Documents/LFF"
```

Now in my shell if I type `cd $WH` it will instantly take me to my shared folder between Ubuntu and Windows 10. They also get loaded each start up so they are permanent.

Hopefully this suggestion helps.

Comment: Shanzam, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks!  Clarification needed:  Does this stick or do I have to run it every time I log in?

Comment: Stick buddy :)....